# How to execute long task in netty?

Tags: java, sql, netty

I'm relative new to netty.io. I'm trying to write an app that insert more than 200 rows the first time the client connects. the problem is that only 10~ rows are inserted at once, looks like netty just interrupts my code. i can't figure out how to set a max execution time for my task.

This is how i'm starting the server:

```
public void start() throws InterruptedException{
        EventLoopGroup group = new NioEventLoopGroup();
        EventExecutorGroup sqlExecutorGroup = new DefaultEventExecutorGroup(10);
        ServerBootstrap server = new ServerBootstrap();
        server.group(group);
        server.channel(NioServerSocketChannel.class);
        server.localAddress(new InetSocketAddress(port));
        server.childHandler(new ChannelInitializer<SocketChannel>(){
            @Override
            protected void initChannel(SocketChannel ch) throws Exception {
                    ch.pipeline().addLast(new HttpServerCodec());
                    ch.pipeline().addLast(new ChunkedWriteHandler());
                    ch.pipeline().addLast(new HttpObjectAggregator(65536));
                    ch.pipeline().addLast(new WebSocketServerProtocolHandler("/"));
                    ch.pipeline().addLast(new WebSocketFrameToByteBuf());
                    ch.pipeline().addLast(new ProtobufEncoder());
                    ch.pipeline().addLast(new ProtobufDecoder(Chat.MsgWrapper.getDefaultInstance()));
                    ch.pipeline().addLast(new MsgUserLogin(prop.getProperty("sessions_prefix")));
           }
        });
        ChannelFuture f = server.bind().sync();
        f.channel().closeFuture().sync();   
    }
```

This is the function inside the handler where im executing the task:

```
private void register(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Chat.User u){
        ctx.executor().execute(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                ctx.channel().attr(Main.KeyUser).set(u);
                ConversationUserMember member =  ConversationPool.getOrCacheConversationUserMember(u);
                ConversationPool.UpdateConversations(member);
                Main.loggedUsers.add(ctx.channel());
                member.newChannel(ctx.channel());
                returnConversations(member,ctx); //this function is the one getting cut by netty.
            //    fireNewUser(u);
            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a little more research i found all the mistakes i was doing:

1. Im not adding an EventExecutorGroup to my handler.
2. The code that do the inserts wasn't releasing the db connections correctly, this was the main problem.
3. In the handler i'm using **ctx.executor().execute** to execute my code, after adding a EventExecutorGroup to the handler, this isn't necessary.

the working code looks like:

```
public void start() throws InterruptedException{
        EventLoopGroup group = new NioEventLoopGroup();
        EventExecutorGroup sqlExecutorGroup = new DefaultEventExecutorGroup(10);
        ServerBootstrap server = new ServerBootstrap();
        server.group(group);
        server.channel(NioServerSocketChannel.class);
        server.localAddress(new InetSocketAddress(port));
        server.childHandler(new ChannelInitializer<SocketChannel>(){
            @Override
            protected void initChannel(SocketChannel ch) throws Exception {
                    ch.pipeline().addLast(new HttpServerCodec());
                    ch.pipeline().addLast(new ChunkedWriteHandler());
                    ch.pipeline().addLast(new HttpObjectAggregator(65536));
                    ch.pipeline().addLast(new WebSocketServerProtocolHandler("/"));
                    ch.pipeline().addLast(new WebSocketFrameToByteBuf());
                    ch.pipeline().addLast(new ProtobufEncoder());
                    ch.pipeline().addLast(new ProtobufDecoder(Chat.MsgWrapper.getDefaultInstance()));
                    ch.pipeline().addLast(sqlExecutorGroup,new MsgUserLogin(prop.getProperty("sessions_prefix")));
           }
        });
        ChannelFuture f = server.bind().sync();
        f.channel().closeFuture().sync();   
    }
```

and:

```
private void register(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Chat.User u){
                ctx.channel().attr(Main.KeyUser).set(u);
                ConversationUserMember member =                          ConversationPool.getOrCacheConversationUserMember(u);
                ConversationPool.UpdateConversations(member);
                Main.loggedUsers.add(ctx.channel());
                member.newChannel(ctx.channel());
                returnConversations(member,ctx); //this function is the one getting cut by netty.
            //    fireNewUser(u);
    }
```

Comment: I still believe your handlers doesnt execute parallely .. check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44398509/how-to-execute-business-logic-handler-in-a-separate-thread-pool-using-netty i m facing the same problem... how do i tell netty to use threads in sqlExecutorGroup to execute tasks parallely