# How to execute business logic handler in a separate thread pool using netty

Tags: java, multithreading, netty, handler

I have a handler that needs to execute some business logic and I want that to be executed in a separate thread pool to not block the io event loop. I have added DefaultEventExecutorGroup into the pipeline as specified in http://netty.io/4.0/api/io/netty/channel/ChannelPipeline.html javadoc and http://netty.io/wiki/new-and-noteworthy-in-4.0.html#no-more-executionhandler---its-in-the-core wiki:

```
ch.pipeline().addLast(new DefaultEventExecutorGroup(10), new ServerHandler());
```

Just for testing purposes my ServerHandler just puts the current thread to sleep for 5 seconds:

```
protected void channelRead0(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Command cmd) throws Exception {
    System.out.println("Starting.");

    try {
        Thread.currentThread().sleep(5000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    System.out.println("Finished.");        
}
```

But apparently the business logic is still executed synchronously:

```
Starting.
Finished.
Starting.
Finished.
Starting.
Finished.
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In case your goal is not to block IO event loop - you did it right. But due to netty specific, your handler will be always attached to the same thread of EventExecutorGroup and thus behavior you described above is expected.

In case you want to execute blocking operation in parallel as soon as it arrives you need to use the another way - separate `ThreadPoolExecutor`. Like this:

```
ch.pipeline().addLast(new ServerHandler(blockingThreadPool));
```

where `blockingThreadPool` is regular `ThreadPoolExecutor`.

For example:

```
ExecutorService blockingThreadPool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);
```

Now, within your logic handler you can submit blocking tasks to this executor like this:

```
protected void channelRead0(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Command cmd) throws Exception {

    blockingIOProcessor.execute(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            System.out.println("Starting.");

            try {
                Thread.currentThread().sleep(5000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            System.out.println("Finished.");
        }
    });

}
```

You can also pass context to this runnable in order to return the response back when processing is finished if needed.

Comment: Well, of course I can always just do this manually but is there netty-way of doing such thing? Since I can pass the EventExecutorGroup to my pipeline handler, can I just somehow also tell it to not use a thread-per-socket approach?

Comment: @TTT the netty way is the way you did it in own code. In case your goal is not to block IO threads - you did it right. In case you want to execute blocking tasks in parallel as soon as they arrive you need to create separate thread pool.

Comment: Shouldn't he reuse the EventExecutorGroup and don't create a new one every time he adds his handler to the pipeline?

Comment: @Eric it depends on the business logic. In general, yes, he shouldn't.

Answer (score -1):

Because the `Netty` handle the request which is sended from same socket by the same `EventExecutor`,so you can start more than one client,and see the result.

Comment: Is it possible to handle each new request as a separate task submitted to thread pool w/o assigning a thread per socket? I want requests from the same client also running in parallel.

Comment: @TTT you can put the `Command`  instance into a `BlockingQueue` container on the method `channelRead` ,and then deal it in your own executor service on other thread.